# Can I use an anonymous type in this situation?

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
   // was before var groupTransactions;
   IEnumerable<IGrouping<TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear, TransactionDto>> groupTransactions = null;

DollarCapPeriod dollarCapPeriod = (DollarCapPeriod)Enum.Parse(typeof(DollarCapPeriod), reward.DollarCapPeriod);
switch (dollarCapPeriod)
{
    case DollarCapPeriod.Monthly:
        groupTransactions = filterdTransactions.GroupBy(x => new { x.TransactionDate.Month, x.TransactionDate.Year });
        break;
    case DollarCapPeriod.Yearly:
  groupTransactions = filterdTransactions.GroupBy(x => new TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear { Month = 0, Year = x.TransactionDate.Year });
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I want to do something like that but it wants the type initialized. So I am wondering is there away around this or do I have to make some sort of concrete type? If so how do I do it again with groupBy?

Sample Data

```
1/14/2012,5,Gas
1/15/2012,5,Gas
1/16/2012,5,Gas
1/17/2012,5,Gas
```

**Edit**

Currently I am trying to do now use a concrete backing but I need to filter by 2 different ways. Sometimes I need only the "Year" and some times I need "Month" and "Year"

I don't know how to do this. They both need to go in the same variable so they need to be the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't confuse anonymous types with inferred types. The `var` keyword does not necessarily mean a type is anonymous. An anonymous type **does not have a name** as far as the developer is concerned (the compiler, of course, gives it one, but that's an implementation detail that you can and should ignore). An inferred type, using the `var` keyword, **could** have a name, you just didn't have to type it.

It is never allowed to say:

```
var x;
```

because there is no information from which to infer the type.

In the general case, you can use anonymous types in scoping situations like loops, try/catch, etc. by initializing a new instance of the anonymous type ahead of time:

```
var x = new { Month = 0, Year = 0 };
switch (foo)
{
  case 1:
    x = new { transaction.Month, transaction.Year };
}
```

As long as the field names and types match between the two anonymous type initializers, the "actual" type is the same.

In your specific case, though, you don't want just an anonymous type, because `GroupBy`doesn't returning an anonymous type. It returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, and in your case only `TKey` is anonymous. While it is **possible** to declare that type in code, it's very hard, and would involve temporary variables being declare solely to get their anonymous `typeof()` information out of them. It would almost certainly be an unmaintainable mess.

Instead you should just declare a type to use at your group key. It's still going to be ugly, on account of the nested generics, but nowhere near as bad as trying to use the anonymous type.

```
public class TransactionGroup
{
  public int Month;
  public int Year;
}
```

and get your grouping:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TransactionGroup, Transaction>> groupTransaction;
var period = (Period)Enum.Parse(typeof(Period), record.Period);
switch (period)
{
    case Period.Monthly:
        groupTransaction = transactions.GroupBy(x => new TransactionGroup
          {
            Month = x.TransactionDate.Month, 
            Year = x.TransactionDate.Year 
          });
        break;
    case Period.Yearly:
        groupTransaction = transactions.GroupBy(x => new TransactionGroup
          {                 
            Month = 0, 
            Year = x.TransactionDate.Year 
          });
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Ok So how about the Yearly switch one I have. I just want to group it by year but still use groupTransaction store it. It is just in some cases I need to group by Month and Year and sometimes only by Year. I thought of building something store the linq(think it would Func<>) then pass it to the group by after the switch but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: The easiest option there would be to group everything by Month = 0, since you aren't interested in the actual month. Some people might argue that the "magic number" approach is wrong but the alternatives are far less maintainable, IMO. I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: I thought of doing that but it never seemed to group them. Instead of having group 1 group when grouped by just "Year" I had 28 groups.

Comment: If you are getting the wrong number of groups you need to look at the values of your group key and see why they are different.

Comment: Well in my list I have many different months. I would think they would not group then. I don't care about the months in this scenario but they may be set to all different types of months.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many months you have in your data if you explicitly group by "Month = 0"; all of your key values will be "Month = 0, Year = trans.Year", so you should have at most one key value per year. If you are getting multiple key values per year, with different months, then you must be explicitly including the Month in the grouping-by-year operation.

Comment: I will post what I have and some sample data.

Comment: Sample data is up as you can see the date pretty much just increments by one day and I have 27 of them. When I just groupby "year" I get 1 record when I group by Month = 0 and Year = transaction.Year I get 27 records.

Answer (score 0):

No, in this case you have to define a concrete type, if you want to declare the `groupTransaction` variable before the switch. You could use anonymous types with the var keyword only when you are declaring and immediately initializing the variable.

So you could define a model which will be used for the grouping:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<MyModel, SourceType>> groupTransaction = null;
DollarCapPeriod dollarCapPeriod = (DollarCapPeriod)Enum.Parse(typeof(DollarCapPeriod), reward.DollarCapPeriod);
switch (dollarCapPeriod)
{
    case DollarCapPeriod.Monthly:
        groupTransaction = filterdTransactions.GroupBy(x => new MyModel { x.TransactionDate.Month, x.TransactionDate.Year });
        break;
    case DollarCapPeriod.Yearly:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Ok that's what I though. So how do I make it concrete? Do I just go new MyClassName {A = x.A}};

Comment: What is it grouping it by. I want to group by Month and Year but I pretty much going to be using the same class that Transaction is in. Right now filterdTransactions has 3 properties(transaction,amount,dollarcap)

Comment: for the yearly one I want to group by just by "Year" can I use MyModel for this and  just not set "Month"?

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
dynamic groupTransaction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the "var" keyword. The "var" keyword is a convenience keyword that allows you to implicitly declare variables based on the type being assigned. You **can** achieve this using several methods including generic and dynamic typing.

**note: using 'object' this way is considered bad coding practice**
You could just set the variable as an object:

```
object groupTransaction = null;
```

You could also declare it dynamic in which case you lose intellisense support and some compile-time syntax checking, plus you may have to cast the variable in certain cases:

```
dynamic groupTransaction = null;
```